# How to make image pop up with a button press?

Tags: ios, image, button

I want to make a simple code that when a button is tapped, an image comes up. I am using xcode 5.1. I am a complete noob, so please explain thoroughly.

Comment: what do you want ask properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the button tapped use this method.

```
-(IBAction)buttontapped:(id)sender
            {

           UIImageView *img1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Name of your   image"]];
                img1.frame=CGRectMake(100, 75, 125, 351)//set Your imageview frame;

                [self.view addSubview:img1];

         img1.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.0);
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                                      delay:0.0
                                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                                 animations:^{
                                     img1.transform =    CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/10), 1.7,1.7);
                                     //CGAffineTransformRotate(img1.transform, M_PI/2);

                                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
             }];
         [img1 startAnimating];
            }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for showing me this code. However, when I use it on the line [self.view addSubview:img1]; it gives me an error. What should I do?

Comment: can you tell me your error ?

Comment: Don't worry I fixed the problem.